# Latex environment setting

Tags: php, html, web-services, latex, mathjax

I am opened a free  site in [Weebly](http://www.weebly.com) . I want to post there regular Latex math equation. Is it possible to set the LAtex language there. If not possible then any other way to set there?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MathJax on Weebly. To quote from [here](http://checkmyworking.com/2012/01/how-to-get-beautifully-typeset-maths-on-your-blog/#weebly):

> Click on the Design tab at the top of the page, then click on the Edit HTML/CSS button at the bottom-left. For each file listed under the Page Layouts section of the editor, paste the following code just after the line with the  tag on it:

```
 <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
                       displayMath: [['\\[','\\]'], ['$$','$$']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

> Click on the Save button at the top-right, pick a name for your theme (or leave the default one), and then publish your site. You’re done! Here’s how it looks on my Weebly site.

Comment: There are some options : `Add new layout`

 `   tall-header.html`
   ` short-header.html`
    `no-header.html`
   ` landing.html
    `splash.html`  which one will I select and where?

Comment: As the quote says: "for each file [...]".

Comment: I've updated the answer since cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, cf. https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.